# handling button click in notification

Tags: android, notifications, onclicklistener

I have got a notification with one Button and I want to do something, when I click the button of the notification.

Is there a possibility like `OnClickListener` to handle that?

Here is the code for the notification:

```
 private void notification_anzeigen(){


    Intent intent = new Intent(this, GestureAnyWhere.class);

    // String notificationMessage = "GestureAnyWhere läuft im Hintergrund";

    // intent.putExtra("NotificationMessage", notificationMessage);
    // intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);


    PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);

    // build notification
    // the addAction re-use the same intent to keep the example short
    Notification n  = new Notification.Builder(this)
            .setContentTitle("GestureAnyWhere läuft im Hintergrund")
            //.setContentText("GestureAnyWhere muss im Hintergrund ausgeführt werden, um Gesten zu erkennen")
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)       // muss rein, ansonsten wird keine Notifikation angezeigt
            .setContentIntent(pIntent)
            .addAction(R.drawable.ic_launcher, "Plus-Button", pIntent)
            .setStyle(new Notification.BigTextStyle().bigText("Auf den Plus-Button drücken, um auf aktueller Seite Gesten zu erkennen"))
            .setAutoCancel(true).build();

    n.setLatestEventInfo(getApplicationContext(), "Plus-Button", "neu", pIntent);


    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.notify(0, n);
}
```

Sorry that the question isn't clear. So I try to specifiy it a little bit better:

- I have got a background service which starts, when I minimize my application
- when the service is starting, a new notification will be shown to inform the user, that the application works in background now
- The background service shall be there in order to detect gestures, which are drawn outside the application
- When I click onto the notification and the application starts again, the service shall be stoped (otherwise I can draw inside my application and not click onto something anymore) -> so that is the first point I want to do: stop a background service, when I click onto the notification
- When I mimimize my application and start the service I am only able to draw onto the homescreen right now -> so that is the second point I want to do: when the user click onto a button under the notification an Activity shall be called in order that the user could draw on the current View

Because I only want to know how a click onto a notification (or a Button under the notification) is handled in generally I don't provide the code for the service and all other stuff.

I hope the question and what I want to do is a little bit clearer.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: And what exactly do you want to do? You could broadcast your intent and handle it in a `BroadcastReceiver`, or you could attach an extra to the intent and check for it in your `Activity`.

Comment: Question is not clear, please edit your question what exactly you want to do???

Comment: sorry. I tried to explain the question better this time

Answer (score 0):

Well, as I understand you want to stop service as soon as you return back to activity.
To do that you may add some extra into inner Intent of PendingIntent.
Parse this extra from intent in your activity (onCreate and onNewIntent if necessary) and then call Context.stopService()